# trouble installing subversion on fedora

Tags: svn, fedora

I'm having trouble installing subversion on fedora.  when i run:

## yum install subversion

I get the following error:

Transaction Check Error:
  package cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.22-8.fc8.x86_64 (which is newer than cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.22-7.i386) is already installed
  package openldap-2.3.39-3.fc8.x86_64 (which is newer than openldap-2.3.38-3.fc8.i386) is already installed
  file /usr/share/man/man5/ldap.conf.5.gz from install of openldap-2.3.38-3.fc8.i386 conflicts with file from package openldap-2.3.39-3.fc8.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/ldif.5.gz from install of openldap-2.3.38-3.fc8.i386 conflicts with file from package openldap-2.3.39-3.fc8.x86_64

Error Summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to first upgrade your existing packages. I've seen a similar behaviour on RHEL when the packages were out of date and I tried to install ImageMagick. For some reason yum is (sometimes) unable to calculate the dependencies if packages are outdated.

So, run first `yum update` and after that `yum install subversion`. Though you seem to be running an ancient Fedora 8, so I'm not sure if that works ...